# getting 403 access forbidden on heroku

Tags: node.js, api, http, heroku

### You don't have access on this server on heroku

I have an app that makes request to `https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/losers/niftyLosers1.json`

and it's always gives error of that
i got same error on railway how do i solve this error?
i tried with railway.app too but that also gives same error

i have tried :

- proxies with httpAgent
- made a serverless app on vercel so i could get that request on it and send back the result and i just request that app instead but that was also a fail, vercel has 10 sec timeout

Comment: Simply copy-pasting that URL into my browser works, so could you just make a regular HTTP request?

Comment: i can access that site but on heroku it's not working as expected